# Build AOSP failed

Tags: android, android-source, android-build

I've sync all the code local. Run such commands:

1.source build/envsetup.sh

2.lunch aosp_crosshatch-userdebug

```
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=Tiramisu
PLATFORM_VERSION=Tiramisu
TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_crosshatch
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_ARCH=arm64
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-a
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=generic
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=arm
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-a
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=generic
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-3.10.0-1062.18.1.el7.x86_64-x86_64-Ubuntu-14.04.6-LTS
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=AOSP.MASTER
OUT_DIR=out
PRODUCT_SOONG_NAMESPACES=device/google/crosshatch hardware/google/av hardware/google/camera hardware/google/interfaces hardware/google/pixel hardware/qcom/sdm845 vendor/google/camera vendor/qcom/sdm845 vendor/google/interfaces vendor/google_devices/common/proprietary/confirmatioui_hal vendor/google_nos/host/android vendor/google_nos/test/system-test-harness vendor/google_devices/crosshatch/proprietary/hardwareinfo
```

Before the lunch command, I did a change in the file build/soong/ui/build/sandbox_linux.go: adding a parameter "--disable_clone_newuser" in the nsjail command in the file. Without the parameter, there will be a error "Operation not permitted" which I think the root cause might be my Linux kernel is 3.1.

3.m

```
Error:
In file included from build/make/core/config.mk:1218:
In file included from build/make/core/soong_config.mk:12:
build/make/core/dex_preopt_config.mk:157: error: fopen failed.
06:29:13 dumpvars failed with: exit status 1

failed to build some targets (1 seconds)
```

I tried command "lunch aosp_arm-eng" and "m" but got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

If you have made any changes, please show those too in the question.

If you haven't changed anything,
Please make sure you have added proper [driver binaries](https://developers.google.com/android/drivers#crosshatch) (vendor codes) and try a clean before the build.

Command for clean: `make clean`

Comment: I did download the crosshatch driver binaries in the aosp folder, unzip them and run the 2 sh file before I ran the command "m". I also made a change before the "lunch" command: add a "--disable_clone_newuser" parameter in the build/soong/ui/build/sandbox_linux.go file when called nsjail command in it. Add the "--disable_clone_newuser" is trying to fix the "Operation not permitted" error while running the "lunch" command. I don't know if the change caused the “fopen failed” error.

Comment: @rockrock Did you use `sudo` at anytime during the process? i.e while creating the download directory or initializing the repo? What is the directory permission of your AOSP root folder? You might want to check out this github thread: [--disable_clone_newuser ignored](https://github.com/google/nsjail/issues/78)

Comment: I build the AOSP in a docker with an Ubuntu image and run the docker image in the root user. So it's the same as use sudo at anytime. The permission of AOSP folder is "drwxr-xr-x".

Comment: does it work if you change the permission to 777? @rockrock